# Related comboboxes, add a third combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do a related combobox. I already have 2 comboboxes, but now I want to add a third.

I have this code for the 2nd combo box.

I'm using windows forms.
The entire code: https://repl.it/@devilonline/MuddyPartialBytecode#main.cs

```
private string[] GetCastById(int id)
{
    return nomes.Where(line => line.movies_id== id).Select(l => l.nomes).ToArray();
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    int id = nomes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].id;
    foreach (string name1 in GetCastById(id))
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(name1);
    }
}
```

[print](https://ibb.co/j37KZRH)

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish and what problem do you have? What that third ComboBox would be for? Your code here sounds fine, please provide more details about your problem.

Comment: I dont know if you can see this:

Comment: ok I've checked the link and I can see where the problem is, please edit your question to include the 3rd Combobox code and delete your answer for clarity

Comment: done. where ist he problem

Answer (score 2):

It is obvious that you are clearing the `Items` of the `comboBox1` then try to get the id of the selected item, which should throw an exception because no item will be selected by then:

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear(); // here the items are cleared
int id = nomes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].id; // nomes[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] = -1
```

Based on your database, the cast table is related to the movies so each movie has a corresponding list of cast, you should then get the id of the selected movie rather than the selected nome:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    int id = movies[comboBoxMovie.SelectedIndex].id; // here we used comboBoxMovie
    foreach (string name1 in GetCastById(id))
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(name1);
    }
}
```

Comment: i can get it work. Here what i acomplish [link](http://example.com)https://imagehost7.online-image-editor.com/oie_upload/images/10185838M5k53Zixo/oie_animation.gif.    I update the project [link](https://repl.it/@devilonline/MuddyPartialBytecode#main.cs)

Comment: I'm sorry I had a typo in my code, try this: instead of `nomes[comboBoxMovie.SelectedIndex].id`, replace `nomes` with `movies`: `movies[comboBoxMovie.SelectedIndex].id`. You need the id from the `movies` list not the `nomes` sorry for that, I will change it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to use databinding through a System.ComponentModel.BindingList<>. Below is a working example. Note, I've added get methods inside the classes for simplicity of populating the ComboBoxes for this example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Form1
{
    class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Category(int id, string name)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            return new List<Category>()
            {
                new Category(1, "Action"),
                new Category(2, "Comedy")
            };
        }
    }

    class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public Movie(int id, string name, int catId)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.CategoryId = catId;
        }

        public static List<Movie> GetMovies()
        {
            return new List<Movie>()
            {
                new Movie(1, "Rambo", 1),
                new Movie(2, "Delta Force", 1),
                new Movie(3, "Elf", 2),
                new Movie(4, "Space Balls", 2)
            };
        }
    }

    class Cast
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Names { get; set; }
        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        public Cast(int id, string names, int movieId)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Names = names;
            this.MovieId = movieId;
        }

        public static List<Cast> GetCast()
        {
            return new List<Cast>()
            {
                new Cast(1, "Silvester Stalone", 1),
                new Cast(2, "Chuck Norris", 2),
                new Cast(3, "Will Farrell", 3),
                new Cast(4, "John Candy", 4)
            };
        }
    }

    private BindingList<Category> _categoryBindingList = new BindingList<Category>();
    private BindingList<Movie> _moviesBindingList = new BindingList<Movie>();
    private BindingList<Cast> _castBindingList = new BindingList<Cast>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your database calls would replace these Get methods.
        Category.GetCategories().ForEach(x => _categoryBindingList.Add(x));
        Movie.GetMovies().ForEach(x => _moviesBindingList.Add(x));
        Cast.GetCast().ForEach(x => _castBindingList.Add(x));

        ComboBox1.DataSource = _categoryBindingList;
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

        ComboBox2.DataSource = _moviesBindingList.Where(x => x.CategoryId == (Category)ComboBox1.SelectedValue.Id).ToList();
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";

        ComboBox3.DataSource = _castBindingList.Where(x => x.MovieId == (Movie)ComboBox2.SelectedValue.Id).ToList();
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Names";
    }

    private void ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox2.DataSource = _moviesBindingList.Where(x => x.CategoryId == (Category)ComboBox1.SelectedValue.Id).ToList();
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";

        ComboBox3.DataSource = _castBindingList.Where(x => x.MovieId == (Movie)ComboBox2.SelectedValue.Id).ToList();
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Names";
    }

    private void ComboBox2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox3.DataSource = _castBindingList.Where(x => x.MovieId == (Movie)ComboBox2.SelectedValue.Id).ToList();
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Names";
    }
}
```